# Is $\mathbb{R}^n$ a variety of $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, complex-numbers

My motivation for this question is that I'm wondering if the subspace Zariski topology of $\mathbb{R}^n\subseteq\mathbb{C}^n$ is the same as the Zariski topology over $\mathbb{R}^n$, something that would be true if $\mathbb{R}^n$ was a variety of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Since for one variable, $\Im(z)=0$ gives me the real axis I can easily generalise this to $n$ variables. I can write $\Im(z)=\frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}$, so my question reduces to:

> Is there a way to express $\overline{z}$ as a complex polynomial on the variable $z$?

Comment: Conjugation is not analytic but polynomials are analytic.

Comment: Polynomials are entire functions. $\overline{z}$ is not. On the other hand, your original question depends on which $\mathbb{R}^n\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ and $n$. For example, in $\mathbb{C}^4$, the variety $z_4=z_3=0$, is an $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Thanks @edm I forgot even the basics of complex analysis!

Comment: As an alternative proof, could you just say that the zero-set of a polynomial is discrete, while the real-line is not?

Comment: @Joe That property is only good in dimension $1$. In higher dimension the zero set of a polynomial is not discrete. For example $z_1=0$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$ is a whole plane of points.

Comment: @yixing Ahh that's a very good point. I didn't think about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If $\bar z = f(z)$ was a polynomial in $z$, then $\|z\|=z\cdot\bar z=z\cdot f(z)=:g(z)$ would be a complex polynomial whose only zero is $0$, therefore you'd have $g(z)=\alpha \cdot z^{k+1}$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$ and $\alpha\in\Bbb C^\times$, hence $f(z)=\alpha\cdot z^k$. Substituting $2$ and $3$ for $z$ quickly leads to the conclusion that $f(z)=z$ or $2^{-k}=\alpha=3^{-k}$, the latter being absurd. This yields the contradiction $-i=f(i)=i$.